# AWS Cloudwatch for unused accounts

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-iam

Is there any possibility for getting a report on unused user accounts using cloudwatch ?
Requirement : Need to get a report on the accounts which is unused for more than 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all used User accounts with Cloudtrail, it would then be a text processing exercise to find the unused ones.